# Network activity for decision to suspend/hibernate

Tags: suspend, cron, network-monitoring

i have a small server (ubuntu server) which i am using on demand. Meaning it switches on from suspend on request. I was trying to find a way, using cron to put the server to sleep after 90 min of network inactivity.

Until now I found only ways to detect the ssh activity, which i would include too.

Can you point me into the right direction? After searching and playing with tools for a day, i am lost on this one.
I didn't find a adequate program nor a possible solution for usage in cron.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the packet count on the network interface to decide to shutdown the VM from the cron job, if I have understood correctly.

You can look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349576/linux-retrieve-per-interface-sent-received-packet-counters-ethernet-ipv4-ipv)

You could make a shell script that checks the number of packets since 90 minutes by using `/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_packets` for interface **eth0**

Comment: Thanks, it brings me closer at least. Any idea how much packages could be considered very low - no traffic?

Comment: That is up to you.